# How to move (Drag and Drop) wpf window when windows is maximized mode

Tags: c#, wpf

How to move (Drag and Drop) wpf window when windows is maximized mode. I am using below code but when window is maximized mode then its not working.

```
 private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    { 
       if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            this.DragMove();
        }
    }
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown Event, Change WindowState to Normal by code and after it apply  DragMove Method.

```
   private void Grid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {            
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }

            DragMove();           
        }
```

Comment: hi guys, when we set   WindowState = WindowState.Normal; then its first resize the window then mouse position and window position  will be differ, and can not accept behavior of window. you can check on your visual studio

Answer (score 0):

When subscribe to Mouse move evet you can change window enter code heresize and location. For example

```
`if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
   {
       this.Width = this.ActualWidth;
       this.Height = this.ActualHeight;
       this.Left = 0;
       this.Top = 0;
       this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
       this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }`
```

Comment: I need this functionality with resizing mode. with keep the position same of mouse and and application window  both.